# ImageView Not Displaying on Reusable TableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have a `TableView` and `TableViewCell` created on my `ViewController`. The cell will be reusable (importing name + photo from database). **Currently only the name cell text shows up.**

**How can I get the image to show above the cell text**(name). Or will I need to create a separate cell subclass? Trying to make something like this:
[image]

#### Storyboard Setup

[image]

#### Update

Added ImageView(inside the cell) to storyboard and made an outlet to `FeedCell.swift`:

```
@IBOutlet weak var setImage: UIImageView!
```

Added to ViewController's `ViewDidLoad`:

```
self.tableView.registerClass(FeedCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "RestaurantCell")
```

Updated ViewControllers `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("RestaurantCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    var imageSet: PFObject?{
        didSet{
            self.fetchImage(restaurantArray[indexPath.row] as? PFObject, completionHandler: {
                (image, error) -> () in
                if image != nil {
                    FeedCell().setImage.image = image
                    cell.imageView?.image = image!
                    cell.imageView?.image = image
                    cell.accessoryView = UIImageView()
                }else{
                    //alert user: no image or put placeholder image
                }
            })
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: there is a list of check boxes at the bottom of attributes tab in the interface builder, called "Installed". after selecting the image within your cell template, please try checking the top-most "Installed" box.

Comment: @tt_emrah Thanks, but i don't see any "installed" box on the imageview attributes.

Comment: a screenshot would be sufficient, i guess. :)
http://i.imgur.com/arNUXEd.png

Answer (score 0):

You have a "`RestaurantCell`", but from the Storyboard screenshot you've included in your question, it looks like it's just a completely blank cell with an empty content view.

If you don't want to create a custom UITableViewCell, you should change that prototype `RestaurantCell` to have both a centered image and a label just underneath it, both exposed via properties that have unique tags set with them.  Then, when the properties get set, you can update the view corresponding to the tag (e.g. view # 1 might be the image, view # 2 might be the name, etc.).

Or, you can simply subclass UITableViewCell and then you'll be able to use IBOutlets, which will be a lot cleaner versus using manual property setters and tags.

Then you can easily set the image and the label text and it should appear just beautifully in the Munchery app.

You might want to also include extra IBOutlets to set the Chef's imageView (Chef Alex is one of my favorites) and the cart button ("+Add", which I think swaps with "In The Bag"?).

***EDITED TO BE MORE SPECIFIC***

Get rid of "`FeedCell().setImage.image = image`".  That's not doing anything good.

Change

```
 let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("RestaurantCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
```

to:

```
 let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("RestaurantCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as FeedCell
```

Also, is the IBOutlet in FeedCell connected to `imageView` or is the outlet named something else?

Comment: thanks for the great answer and cool that you've tried Munchery :) But I'm fairly new with XCode so I don't think I implemented the subclass correctly. I added an update to my code above with my changes. Still can't get the image to show.

Comment: Did you lay out your cell subclass in your storyboard or a separate xib file anywhere?  I'm still thinking you are using a completely empty cell with nothing inside the content view.  Your app has a complex cell layout, so you shouldn't be using default cells, but instead you should have a custom cell with a custom layout.

Comment: I didn't lay out the cell subclass or make an xib. I just set `RestaurantCell's` class to FeedCell and added the imageView to the cell inside the `ViewController` in storyboard and added the outlet. http://i.imgur.com/YJjc3BJ.png

Comment: I made the changes but nothing seems to be showing up still. The IBOutlet is connected. I think i need to make `setImage = image` for the image to show. Somethng like:  `cell.setImage.image = image` ?

Comment: `setImage` isn't it.  You'd want something like `cell.imageView?.image = image`.  I'm still not convinced your `IBOutlet` is connected, though.

Comment: I connected the imageview outlet to FeedCell.swlft. http://i.imgur.com/ggqvzLQ.png  http://i.imgur.com/tl33KH9.png

Comment: "`setImage`" is an incredibly bad & potentially confusing outlet name, but in this case "`cell.setImage.image = image`" should work.  I'd recommend changing the name to something else, like "`mainEntreeImageView`".

Comment: I changed the name. Now using `cell.restaurantImageView.image = image` It still doesn't display anything. I added a dummy label to the cell to see if the label would even show. But it doesn't show. I'm thinking the subclassed cell isn't connected to the tableview?